# How to create a drawer in iphone?

Tags: iphone

i just want to know how to create a dropdown menu when a button is clicked, just shown in the image.![image][1]

When I click "Default Language" button it should show a list of options to select from. And when this list appears, the other buttons (or rows) below the "Default Language" button should move down so that they are not covered by the popped list.

Regards Nipin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple. It basically uses a table view and gestures to open up and close different sections of a cell.

Comment: but this is not the tableview,this is button

Comment: Right, but don't you think a table view suits this scenario better than a button

Comment: but is a subview whaich i displayed above,i need the button to act like this.do u have any idea about this?thanks